# Error while installing 3G USB stick driver on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, usb-modem

I am getting the error shown below. I'm new to Ubuntu. How do I resolve it?

```
> install.sh: 187: [: true: unexpected operator
udevadm is exist!
******Begin to /opt/TATA_DOCOMO_3G/driver
this is linux driver installtion
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-45-generic-pae/build M=/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.1.2 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-45-generic-pae'
  CC [M]  /tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.1.2/onda.o
/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.1.2/onda.c:18427:22: fatal error: usb-wwan.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.1.2/onda.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.1.2] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-45-generic-pae'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
this  is customized kernel ,kernel version is: 3.2.0-45-generic-pae
enter customize_driver_install function
cp: cannot stat `onda.ko': No such file or directory
FATAL: Module onda not found.
disselfirefox.pp driver_install.run nm.pp readme_onda.txt se End to /opt/TATA_DOCOMO_3G/driver
install.sh: 426: [: true: unexpected operator
install completed!!!
....After setup, you will find the TATA DOCOMO 3G in "Applications->Internet->TATA DOCOMO 3G". Click the TATA DOCOMO 3G and the application will run
install.sh: 434: read: Illegal option -n
./TATA_DOCOMO_3G: error while loading shared libraries: libqt-mt.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you include the exact model of the USB 3G stick? Please run `lsusb` in a terminal and post the output in your question. Usually operators just rebrand existing (supported) dongles and pretend to have manufactured it themselves. Don't be fooled. And are you sure you need this driver? What are the indications for you that it doesn't work out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont really need to install the driver. Most of the drivers come preinstalled in the kernel. Try looking for "New Mobile Broadband connection" entry in the network icon on the top of the screen. It appears a few seconds after the modem turns on. I am able to use my Reliance 3G dongle (its a ZTE MF668A) here without installing any drivers... so i think even you won't be needing them.